# error creating spring bean in zk with session = scope

Tags: spring, mvvm, spring-security, inversion-of-control, zk

In application context when i have

```
    <beans:bean id="Facade"
      class="com.facade.Facade"/>
```

every thing works fine i can access facade using `SpringUtil.getBean("Facade")`

but if i add `session = scope` i.e

```
<beans:bean id="Facade"
      class="com.facade.Facade" scope="session"/>
```

i get the below error.... How to fix it ?
I am using `zk` + `spring security`

```
     [java] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'F
acade': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you inte
nd to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found:
Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request? If you are actually operating within a web req
uest and still receive this message,your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In thi
s case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

Comment: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/42207-scope-session-bean-problem solves the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comment is indeed correct for the solution.
But why do you want a facade to be in the session scope?

With other words you will create this bean again and again for each session that you have.
So if 5 users log in you have 5 beans of the same class. 
Is that still the wanted situation?

Greetz chill.

Comment: you are correct.. it should not be in session scope ... i was just testing the zk session scope